# Series definite integral of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

A question posed to me. Does my input and output look correct?
[image]

Comment: You should check the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html

Comment: Lots of usefull stuff there!!!!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to MathematicaSE. Before you post another question like this please check documentation and ask only in case of serious doubts, this is not a place to verify one line homeworks. Minimal MMA knowledge is required to accept the question as on topic. Don't want to discourage you in general, just put some effort here.

Answer (score 3):

The exact integral is

```
 exact = Integrate[1/(1 + x^5), {x, 0, 1/5}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Which is approximately,

```
exact // N // InputForm

(*  0.19998933519474205  *)
```

Approximating the integrand by its truncated series expansion

```
series5 = Series[1/(1 + x^5), {x, 0, 5}] // Normal

(*  1 - x^5  *)

approx5 = Integrate[series5, {x, 0, 1/5}]

(*  18749/93750  *)
```

Which is approximately,

```
approx5 // N // InputForm

(*  0.19998933333333332  *)

(exact - approx5)/exact // N

(*  9.30754*10^-9  *)
```

Using a more accurate series expansion

```
series10 = Series[1/(1 + x^5), {x, 0, 10}] // Normal

(*  1 - x^5 + x^10  *)

approx10 = Integrate[series10, {x, 0, 1/5}]

(*  644496881/3222656250  *)
```

Which is approximately,

```
approx10 // N // InputForm

(*  0.19998933519515152  *)

(exact - approx10)/exact // N

(*  -2.0475*10^-12  *)
```